# Connect user to socket only after login - Node.js + socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, jwt

I'm writing a REST API server with express in Node.js, and I want to use socket.io for RT chat and connections between users.

I want to connect the user to the socket only after login.
If the user entered the right credentials, I send to the client the token (using JWT):

```
const accessToken = jwt.sign({
user_id: user_id},
publicToken,
{expiresIn: '3d'});

res.send(accessToken);
```

How can I enforce connection to the socket **only after the authentication**?

Comment: simply dont init the `io()` code if not signed in

Comment: thank you, do you mean that client side should init the io() after the login?